# Certificate Installation Access Denied Error

Tags: c#, ssl, client-certificates

I am trying to add a certificate inside localMachine Root. Below is the code for what I tried but this is not allowing me to add into Local Machine, while coming to add it say's access denied. How to allow to install inside Local Machine?

```C#
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"D:\MyCertificate.pfx", "Temp@1234",
                X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
// save certificate and private key
X509Store storeMy = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
storeMy.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
storeMy.Add(cert);
```

Comment: Have you tried to run application as Admin?

Comment: @Scorpion:When i tried to run application as admin this worked.Why this is not working even user having admin rights?any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to Run application as Admin.

If it works successfully as an admin that means your user doesn't have access to install the certificate.

Please read through [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731899.aspx)

You can try to install the certificate under `current user` store rather than `local machine`.

In code use:

```
StoreLocation.CurrentUser
```

instead of

```
StoreLocation.LocalMachine
```

Answer (score 9):

Make sure `Identity` property of `Application Pool` you are using for your application is set to Local System.

[image]

Comment: this is doing through windows application not web, so where i can set Identity property to Local System

Comment: worked for me!!! I was having Access denied issue in IIS.