# X509Certificate2 - Access Denied Exception if use ECC certificate

Tags: c#, public-key-encryption, x509certificate2, elliptic-curve, pkcs#7

I try to encrypt and decrypt data with `System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs`, but it works only with **RSA** certificates, if I used an **ECC** (curve ECDH_brainpoolP512r1) certificate the constructor of `X509Certificate2` crashes with an `Access Denied` Exception.

#### Create SelfSignedCertificate in Powershell

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate `
 -Subject "CN=Test Code Signing RSA" `
 -Type DocumentEncryptionCert `
 -KeyUsage "DigitalSignature" `
 -FriendlyName "Test Code Signing" `
 -NotAfter (get-date).AddYears(5) `
 -KeyExportPolicy Exportable `
 -SmimeCapabilities ` 
 -KeyAlgorithm ECDH_brainpoolP512r1
```

#### Read SelfSignedCertificate in code

```
var base64cert = "MIIF/wIBAzCCBbsGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCBawEggWoMIIFpDCCAkcGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCAjgEggI0MIICMDCCAiwGCyqGSIb3DQEMCgECoIIBNjCCATIwHAYKKoZIhvcNAQwBAzAOBAi2P5j9EliEaQICB9AEggEQyJLkopAMyHJh0jQXtnlwK4yjpE0WqYXf9sNPPLOFXgaxNU7gLKc3F6kPJUxLCxnvjOe7bRJS3v4A0GQBBqeFEJjBT9hd88RaQ2NsNxDrQEh/ZAyTUg+l6CyApUtcJb5uehPVnj7xnWtu4vvxDh5hRqSVxSR50wOjk/MKlyX1hhF1JybzRiqESKIMLx84HWJqZ6Fp87asJ0/0isL+kVxarqLrTkv0CGt2QaLxZzu9YDGj6nuGy2EBQwGHwMCEVTFupX55njV4aU3YTG2U+BHFl667NekTtOXH5GXDbp6D+9PntXBxW2d3E68v7lBVMjPKfTsTeCs4aLOwQzsXIFgvouw6GgGsZCrYaQwMNuGayC4xgeIwDQYJKwYBBAGCNxECMQAwEwYJKoZIhvcNAQkVMQYEBAEAAAAwXQYJKoZIhvcNAQkUMVAeTgB0AGUALQA0ADYANwBmADEAOAAxAGMALQBiAGQAZQA0AC0ANAA5AGUANgAtAGEANABjADMALQA4ADQAOAAwADYAMgBmADIANgA4ADEAMTBdBgkrBgEEAYI3EQExUB5OAE0AaQBjAHIAbwBzAG8AZgB0ACAAUwBvAGYAdAB3AGEAcgBlACAASwBlAHkAIABTAHQAbwByAGEAZwBlACAAUAByAG8AdgBpAGQAZQByMIIDVQYJKoZIhvcNAQcBoIIDRgSCA0IwggM+MIIDOgYLKoZIhvcNAQwKAQOgggLdMIIC2QYKKoZIhvcNAQkWAaCCAskEggLFMIICwTCCAiagAwIBAgIQXQFCNRCYc4hHLhQAD247rTAJBgcqhkjOPQQBMDAxLjAsBgNVBAMMJVRlc3QgQ29kZSBTaWduaW5nIEVDQyBicmFpbnBvb2xQNTEycjEwHhcNMTgwMzAyMTQyMTQ1WhcNMjMwMzAyMTQzMTQ2WjAwMS4wLAYDVQQDDCVUZXN0IENvZGUgU2lnbmluZyBFQ0MgYnJhaW5wb29sUDUxMnIxMIGbMBQGByqGSM49AgEGCSskAwMCCAEBDQOBggAETcwT2kPzMxF5upq+xb2NpTmRk2Gkp1mThVESNI9A1tgWk3wIylN72b1t5yHxveiWdopn3LkeT0hTaXSJ4fZsHmYRo0KZS5fKZbSSiFlLbxAwndgG99HLakz/I59WtXzSenSaM6HkP+Nz0Kmxvvy0umOXLg0bU8qpX5tLUtEFAxOjgd8wgdwwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgeAMBQGA1UdJQQNMAsGCSsGAQQBgjdQATCBlAYJKoZIhvcNAQkPBIGGMIGDMAsGCWCGSAFlAwQBKjALBglghkgBZQMEAS0wCwYJYIZIAWUDBAEWMAsGCWCGSAFlAwQBGTALBglghkgBZQMEAQIwCwYJYIZIAWUDBAEFMAoGCCqGSIb3DQMHMAcGBSsOAwIHMA4GCCqGSIb3DQMCAgIAgDAOBggqhkiG9w0DBAICAgAwHQYDVR0OBBYEFMmLfUI9zvfjMlvbolK8pP0zeZNhMAkGByqGSM49BAEDgYkAMIGFAkEAlCq9PiR4Yl0A+kIZO1yyfmKpcmJI6++jZJJ1P2LxZIi9ZgIJQLIWjmBTMP1nswAzNbnqetOBuJy55+SkO2OsngJAGXIYtW8RBFcTmRYnhCLeIsB/De3khytnaeHNBZVB/x0n/gFqVNMaPZp6l4MPGhEBS8pcvLN4zvO7phxR0Xt3HDFKMBMGCSqGSIb3DQEJFTEGBAQBAAAAMDMGCSqGSIb3DQEJFDEmHiQAVABlAHMAdAAgAEMAbwBkAGUAIABTAGkAZwBuAGkAbgBnAAAwOzAfMAcGBSsOAwIaBBSas13IRWnhNtoPLKp29FJpLmCptgQUkF0JRqyYiDG0Ql7zAPED2uVWzykCAgfQ";
new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(base64cert), "qwert");
```

#### Exception

```
Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: Access Denied
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FilterPFXStore(Byte[] rawData, SafePasswordHandle password, PfxCertStoreFlags pfxCertStoreFlags)
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FromBlobOrFile(Byte[] rawData, String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(Byte[] rawData, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(Byte[] rawData, String password)
   at PkcsEncryption.Program.Certificate(Boolean rsa) in c:\git\PkcsEncryption\PkcsEncryption\Program.cs:line 88
   at PkcsEncryption.Program.Encrypt(Byte[] dataPlain, Boolean useRsa) in c:\git\PkcsEncryption\PkcsEncryption\Program.cs:line 56
   at PkcsEncryption.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\git\PkcsEncryption\PkcsEncryption\Program.cs:line 22
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The PFX which you have encoded as base64 there has internally set the marker indicating it was exported from a machine keystore.  Your Access Denied indicates that you are not running as an administrator (and thus do not have the permission to add keys to the machine's keystore).

To ensure that keys from a PFX get added to the current user's key store set the `X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet` flag.  Or, if you've installed the early access build (or, in the future, the released build) of .NET Framework v4.7.2 you can use `EphemeralKeySet` to keep the private key in memory and avoid the keystore altogether.

```
new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(
    Convert.FromBase64String(base64cert),
    "qwert",
    X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet);
```

Comment: an other solution that helped in my case was this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18637426/6826260